# What are ways that a character can acquire psychic powers?

Tags: fiction, fantasy

I've been trying to get back at writing stuff again and I'm currently, not-per-se stuck, but more so curious if people care to enlighten me on ways a character can acquire psychic powers.

At the time being, the only procedure I can think of is in a form of a head trauma that as a consequence rewires the brain.

I'm open for anything!

Comment: This could be a great question on worldbuilding as well, and I for one would be interested to see the answers there besides the great answers already provided here.

Comment: Watch the movie Phenomenon with John Travolta.  In it he suddenly gets a psychic boost and much of the movie is centered on figuring out what happened.  It's not a bad little flick

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on World building.  This would be a great question over there.

Answer (score 6):

### What is your theme and genre?

In a **sci-fi** world, psychic powers will have a pseudo-science explanation. Abilities will be researched by physicists, exploited by governments, and abused by criminals. There might be psychic olympics, cash prize endowments, and specialized schools to find 'athletes' and develop psychic industries.
Psychic ability is probably catagorical, measurable, and has a long in-world history even if only recently legitimized by science.

In a **dark fantasy** world, psychic powers may be forbidden knowledge and for good reason. Psychics may be driven underground because they are associated with chaos and misery. Practitioners are trained esoterics from secret societies. There may be 'Outsiders' who seek psychic access to our world, or the powerful/aristocratic who desire a psychic shonen (or patsy) because they are unwilling to put themselves at risk.
Ability is probably metered by stock-fantasy tropes like tournament, family lineage, purity of heart/purpose, prophesy, chosen one, etc

In a **horror** world, the psychic incident might be a one-time occurrence connected to a trauma or injustice that wants uncovering, or it might be a monkey's paw curse that goes terribly wrong, or an unwanted connection to a psychopathic killer. Psychic abilities are 'paranormal' in-world, abnormal or so rare that any regular person won't believe the protagonist, among other alienation and persecution tropes (witch burnings, etc).
Abilities and origins are left mostly unexplained or ambiguous.

In a superhero story, sure a conk on the head is fine. Also being cursed by a statue, recruited by a dying alien, maybe bitten by a radioactive spider, or gamma rays from space. **Adventure** stories are often about random chance or being in the right (wrong) place during a rare event.
It doesn't really matter *how* because it was completely un-earned and probably not intentional, likely quite sudden to get the hero to the action sooner, overpowered but unprepared.

**Who is your protagonist? What are their obstacles?**
How 'routine' are psychic abilities? How are psychics treated?
What are the long-term consequences of being psychic, if any?
How are we suppose to *feel* about it?

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways a story could justify giving a person psychic abilities. Broadly, I'd say psychic powers could be a feature of the brain, or supernatural, or technological.

Supposing psychic powers are due to some feature of the brain

- A person might be born with it (e.g. a mutant ability)
- They might develop it by training (i.e. maybe everyone has the potential, but you need to work at it)
- Something might alter their brain to give it that feature

  - Some form of head trauma or accident or disease (e.g. brain cancer)
  - Some physiology-altering technology (either a device, or maybe a mutation-inducing serum)
  - Some sort of brain altering magic

If psychic powers are supernatural

- A person might still be born with it, or develop it through training (you just wouldn't be able to tell from seeing their brain like in the case above)
- A person could acquire it through a magic ritual, or a deal with a magic being (genies, devils, gods)
- A magic item could provide the psychic powers. It could be a ring or necklace you wear, or maybe it comes from a magic gem implanted in the body (possibly in the brain)

If psychic powers have a technological origin

- The most obvious option is a device implanted in the brain.
- But even without implantation, something like a smartphone that lets you read people's mind is like having psychic powers. But without thought-control over the powers I think many people would disqualify it.

Comment: Holy crap! I never thought of brain cancer or mutation in the brain cells! Thanks a bunch, towr!

Comment: They used the brain tumor explanation in the [X-Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pusher_(The_X-Files)) once. Another interesting "disease" option could be a parasite/symbiont.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how "Repeatable" you want the action to get these powers is, setting, and if your audience includes children.

If your audience involves children or you want it to so only the protag and her arch nemesis can have powers, it should probably be mcguffinrays from planet Psyfi, as you don't want anyone to try and recreate them after reading that they might get super powers after eating 200 liquorice and egg sandwiches encase they try and recreate them. This is the route most comic books go.

If its a comedy-esque setting then maybe you *do* want it to be because they got awoken from some inane act such as having a golden earwig finding its way into someone's brain, or disgust after being forced to eat 200 liquorice and egg sandwiches.

If its a more serious setting, you can go for the ever classic scientific experiment  gone awry or any of the various options offered by Towr in their answer.

Comment: And now I want to try a liquorice and egg sandwich. I like them individually, so now I'm going to have to try them together. Lol. Of course, real liquorice, not anise or plastic tasting imitations like Twizzler.

Comment: @computercarguy make sure to update if you get psychic powers

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to put egg salad and liquorice on my grocery list for tonight. And I'd be happy if I even got better short term memory. ;-)

Comment: So, unbelievably, licorice and egg salad makes a pretty good combo. I put a lot of mustard in the egg salad (and no tomato), so the licorice flavor isn't very strong, but the licorice gives it a sweet flavor, and a decent chew. I tried with soft Australian licorice as well as fresh, fairly soft, "regular" black licorice. I'm still eating the sandwich, so it's too early to tell if I have superpowers. ;-) Oh, wait, this was supposed to be just an egg, not egg salad... Well, now I know what I'm having for lunch tomorrow.

Comment: Fried egg sandwiches with licorice also tastes pretty good. There's even a hint of cinnamon flavor, even though there's no cinnamon in either type of licorice I tried. The egg overrode the licorice flavor and the licorice just gave the sandwich a sweeter flavor. Again, I'm surprised this worked so well together.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can have exposure to high psychic energy
2. Lots of training
3. Trauma
4. Some [Darkhold](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Darkhold)-type ritual
5. Venom-type symbiote, but psychic
6. Born with it